# IIS logs have more info on one server vs another

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I have 2 servers with the same IIS configuration and logging fields. One server logs more info than the other. Specifically, the URI Query (cs-uri-query) field. In one server, it doesn't log this field whereas in another it logs the URL being requested. Is there anything else other than the fields selected that affect IIS logs.

For example,

**Server with less info**

2018-06-28 00:00:00 10.55.91.22 GET / 443 - 10.X.X.X ELB-Health/1.0 - 200 0 125 2

**Server with more info in logs**

2018-06-28 00:00:25 10.55.91.22 POST /api/login 443 - X.X.X.X mydomain.com/login 200 0 13 247

**Update:**


The first one doesn't log POST requests. Only the second one does even though the same fields are selected for logging.

Comment: From where do you think the first contains less and the second contains more? GET requests of course look different from POST ones.

Comment: Thank you, @LexLi. I have updated the question.

Comment: "The first one doesn't log POST requests" is also technically impossible. IIS log files record everything it processed (except those handled directly by HTTP.sys, in HTTP error logs). Thus, analyze the server again to see if those log entries went to another site instead.